# Error while reading pdf and setting a template using MPDF - PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter, pdf-generation, mpdf, fpdi

I am trying to read a pdf file, which contains images and formatting and adding new page at the end of that pdf file and then setting pdf password using mpdf in codeigniter 4.1.3 and mpdf version > 8.0.

Plain PDF files without images works completely fine using code below. Can anyone help here?

error as follows -

```
ErrorException #1
Uncaught CodeIgniter\HTTP\Exceptions\HTTPException: Unknown HTTP status code provided with no message: 267 in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/projectname/system/HTTP/ResponseTrait.php:548
Stack trace:
#0 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/projectname/system/HTTP/ResponseTrait.php(548): CodeIgniter\HTTP\Exceptions\HTTPException::forUnkownStatusCode(267)
#1 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/projectname/system/Debug/Exceptions.php(318): CodeIgniter\HTTP\Response->setStatusCode(267)
#2 [internal function]: CodeIgniter\Debug\Exceptions->exceptionHandler(Object(setasign\Fpdi\PdfParser\CrossReference\CrossReferenceException))
#3 {main}
```

```
$this->mpdf->SetDocTemplate($source, true);
$this->mpdf->SetProtection(array('print', 'modify'), '123456', '123456');
$this->mpdf->AddPage();
$this->mpdf->WriteHTML('');
$this->mpdf->Output(APPPATH . "../public/files/" . $fileName, 'F');
```

Comment: How did you add images to PDF? from form upload or in the resource folder?

Comment: @AbdullaNilam Well, I found out that fpdf cannot read files with version greater than 1.4 - so looking for a solution to read files stored with 1.4 and more now. Do you have some idea around it? Images with version <=1.4 doesn't seems a problem.

Comment: @AbdullaNilam We ended up buying a license to read PDF version more than 1.4! Setasign is the name of the provider and now it works well :)

Comment: Happy to hear  "it works well". Good Luck <3